# Is the absolute value of the electron-spin 1/2 a convention or an observable?

Tags: quantum-spin

Could the spin have been defined as 0, 1, 2 and 4 instead of 0, 1/2, 1 and 2? Similar to the choice of electric charge unit -1 for the electron and not -3 or +3. In that case, quarks would have integer charges.
I read that spin 1/2 particles return to their original state after a 4$\pi$ twist and spin 1 after a 2$\pi$ twist. That seems to make the current definition 'physical', not just a convention. Is that correct?

Comment: I mean, of course you can scale the number however you want, it’ll just get confusing.

Comment: There’s no intrinsic “1/2-y ness” of electrons that _requires_ us to describe them using the word “1/2”. The spin is 1/2 of $\hbar$, but that also means it’s twice $\hbar/4$ or $1/4\pi$ of $h$. We use the first phrasing because $\hbar$ is nice and simple.

Comment: @knzhou : no intrinsic "1/2-y ness"? not even their behaviour under rotation? Macroscopically, rotation over 2$\pi$ is the identity operation so that would indeed deserve to be the 'natural unit'. Correct?

Comment: Sure, there is a real sense in which the convention of calling it $1/2$ is less arbitrary than other conventions. But it’s still a convention.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be even more natural to call spin 1/2 spin 2 because it takes two revolutions to return to the original state? (I am not advocating this.)

Comment: @G.Smith: Spin as defined is the intrinsic angular momentum of a particle or collection of particles (as opposed to orbital angular momentum, or, I think, good ol' rigid-body angular momentum).  So no, probably not.  No matter what method of expression you choose, it's going to be weird.

Comment: The observables are $\vec{S}^2$, $S_z$, etc., not the quantum numbers $s$, $m_s$, etc.

Comment: Note that $s$ is not even proportional to $|\vec S|$!

Comment: Choices of how to assign quantum numbers are like choices of coordinate systems: human conventions.

Comment: I get the impression from the comments and answers that the original definition of $\hbar$ as $h/{2\pi}$ and not $h/{4\pi}$ fixed the electron's spin to $1/2$. I believe $h$ was defined in different (non-rotating) context first, and later in context of (orbital) angular momentum. My original question hinges on the presence or absence of arbitrary convention in the choice of unit $\hbar$ instead of half that value. Maybe linear momentum and angular momentum are just 'naturally' related by the $1/{2\pi}$ and not $1/{4\pi}$?

Answer (score 2):

It is in part a convention, but it is also very much driven by the physics of the original Stern-Gerlach experiment.

What is NOT convention is that there are two states of opposite eigenvalues.

In mathematics it is more common to use integers to label representations of a Lie algebra, so in this field people would label the spin-doublet representation as $\lambda=2j=1$, but the raising and lowering operators change $m$ by two units, i.e. the states for the "spin-doublet" would have $\bar m=\pm 1$ in this convention.

The physics convention is driven by the fact that, for spherical harmonics, the raising and lowering operators *must* step $m$ by $\pm 1$, and this convention has been retained for the spin raising and lowering operators, and other properties follow from that choice.  In particular the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of the spin-operators $\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{x,y,z}$ is consistent with this convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the angular momentum using the classical expression, you get a spatial operator that combines momentum and position, for instance:

$$\bf{L}_z = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

and apply the commutation relations $[r_i,p_j]=i \hbar \delta_{ij}$ (plus some other algebra machinery), you would always get an odd number of distinct eigenvalues. The existence of rotational degrees of freedom that have an *even* number of distinct eigenvalues ("+" and "-" polarizations in the case of electrons or Silver atoms as in the original Stern-Gerlach experiment) is hence proof that said operators cannot be written in terms of a combination of the spatial operators above.

Hence the spin operators $\bf{S}$, although they do respect the same commutation relations as the orbital angular momentum operators $\bf{L}$, they are different in the sense that the latter can be associated to a spatial rotation, while the other can only correspond to an "intrinsic" or "internal" rotation of the particle

Answer (score 0):

Spin was introduced to explain two valuedness of atomic spectra and its two valuedness is directly demonstrated by the Stern Gerlach experiment. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment

Comment: This doesn’t seem to answer the question, which did not ask about the two possibilities for spin 1/2. It is asking about the “normalization” of the spin quantum number $s$.